# Tools to compress and store Vmware images

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

Is there any Vmware or 3rd party tool to compress and store large vmdk files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to do is [shrink the virtual disk itself](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_shrink.html) to get rid of unused space. You can then use a compression utility like [7-zip](http://7-zip.org) to get them even smaller.

Comment: Link is out of date

Answer (score 3):

Since this is one of the few questions that popup when googling something about compressing VMWare vm's let me point out some experience with compressing a large 100gb-200gb VM (i'm no expert, so feel free to comment).

- If you are not using snapshots, first cleanup the host os. Use windows disk cleanup, and use something like spacesniffer/windirstat to identify large files/programs you may not need and remove them. This will lower the size of the vmdx.
- If you are using snapshots, the first option is not available, the only thing you can do in that case is remove any and snapshots that you don't use. That will size down the VM aswell. Or remove all snapshots and do the first option if you don't care about those anyways.
- When you need to keep working in the VM and you have the available space, you can copy the VM and zip the copy instead of the original VM. Copying is quite quick if you have a modern SSD (I.e. your disk speed is good)

Then you may want to compress your VM.

- Don't use windows explorer for zipping, use something like 7zip which is generally faster
- Be mindful of any anti-virus software (windows defender) trying to continuously scan the zipfile you're creating lowering the compression speed.
- With taskmanager you can lower the priority of processes, so if you need to continue working on your computer, make sure you set the zipping process (i.e. 7zip.exe) to 'below normal' so it does not hog all CPU resources.
- Don't use the ZIP format if you can, use LMZAA2 (7z) which comes with popular programs like 7zip or PeaZip, (Free)ARC also seems to be a good compression format - but since its not as broadly supported i decided not to use it.
- 7Zip's LMZAA2 can utilize multiple cores to compress files. On my setup the bottleneck was CPU, not disk IO like I had expect - so using the 7z format instead of zip cut the compression time from 6-8 hours down to 3 or something.
- With 7Zip and LMZAA2, the 'normal' setting gives about 40% compression ratio, the 'Ultra' setting gave a ratio of about 44% percent. I did not fully measure the compression time(s), but i'd say 'ultra' is worth using, it did not add much more compression time and the 4% is pretty significant for large files. If this adds much more time decompressing - I don't know.

Then when copying the file to a network share:

- Don't use file explorer, use the command line and run a copy command from windows has about 3 (yeah, 3). If the network shall is in your local area, windows explorer copy may work fine - but over an unreliable network, or when you need the speed - don't use it.
- Windows has 3 copy commands, but it seems consensus that [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) is the one windows 10 will be using moving forward - so i'm using that.

Answer (score 2):

Old post but I'll answer it in case anyone else has the same question. You want to do this to archive unused VMDKs? I don't think there's much benefit to shrinking the VMDK first. Just do a cleanup within the OS (delete unnecessary and temp files, etc). Then use a zip program to compress the VMDK and optionally break it down to smaller chunks. I had to do this to transfer a VMDK to a consultant. I used a quad-core VM with 8 GB RAM using 7-Zip with the ultra compression level and split it into 4480 MB (DVD) size chunks. I got 8 GB per hour at 28% compression ratio. Your mileage will vary.